# NSXMLParser contentsOfURL Vs Data

Tags: swift, nsxmlparser

When parsing an XML file from a server I have always used "`init(data: Data)`"

```
 let url = URL(string: urlString)
 let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
 let parser = XMLParser(data: data as! Data)
```

I read the docs and see this method "`init?(contentsOf: URL)`"

```
let url = URL(string: urlString)
let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url!)
```

Question is then am I unnecessarily converting to a data object from the URL contents, and I may as well just initialise from the URL? Or, is there any merit to creating the data object and parsing from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no semantic difference between the two variants.

For **http(s)** urls you should prefer `init(data:)` or `XMLParser(data:)`, but you should not load you data with `NSData(contentsOf:)`. The reason is that the `contentsOf:` variants will block the current thread with a synchronous request. You should instead load the data asynchronously with `NSURLSession`.

You should use `XMLParser(contentsOf:)` and `Data(contentsOf:)` only for **file** urls.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I call the entire function on a background thread so doesn't block current thread anyway.

Comment: No, you are blocking the background thread. A background thread may be your _current thread_, too. This is not a good solution. Using `NSURLSession` and asynchronous requests is not very difficult. Asynchronous requests are executed by the runloop, and they will block no thread.